# Django custom AdminSite and ModelAdmin

Tags: python, django

I have overridden standard AdminSite with my own one:

**project/admin/base.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin    

class MyAdmin(admin.AdminSite):
    ...    

my_admin = MyAdmin()
```

and registered some application's model with it:
**fact/admin.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from project.admin.base import my_admin
from models import Fact    

class FactAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('section', 'description')


my_admin.register(Fact, FactAdmin)
```

How can I get this model displayed on an index page? I can't use autodiscover as stated here: [How to use custom AdminSite class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877335/how-to-use-custom-adminsite-class)
The workaround suggested in that question also doesn't work for me and I'd like to make it it a more clean way.

The documentation only states that

> There is really no need to use autodiscover when using your own AdminSite instance since you will likely be importing all the per-app admin.py modules in your myproject.admin module.

I don't import per app modules in project.admin module though.
So is there any way to tell custom AdminSite about the registered model and show it on the index?

**Edit:** I have hooked URLs and I see my_admin, not admin. With standard admin everything works correctly. Here is the code of **project/urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from admin.base import my_admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...    
    url(r'^admin/', include(my_admin.urls, app_name='admin')),
)
```

Comment: What is displayed for the moment ? Have you changed your url conf ( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#hooking-adminsite-instances-into-your-urlconf ) too ?

Comment: Yes, I've hooked URLs and I see the admin page with "You don't have permissions to edit anything" on the index page.

Comment: Are you sure your URLs are pointing to `my_admin` and not `admin`?

Comment: Yes they are. I've made an edit that shows the code.

Comment: Are you sure your `app_name` is just `admin`? Shouldn't that be `my_admin`?

Comment: app_name can be anything you want, it's just a string that urlresolver uses to identify url by name.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to do:

```
from django.contrib import admin  
class MyAdmin(admin.AdminSite):
  ...    

admin.site = MyAdmin()
```

Comment: After doing so, I lost users on the main page. How to get them back?

Comment: from django.contrib.auth.models import User
....
....
admin.site.register(User)