# django admin, extending admin with custom views

Tags: python, django

I would like to request some assistance regarding this matter.

I have followed [this](https://www.stavros.io/posts/how-to-extend-the-django-admin-site-with-custom/) guide to add a view to my admin.

I am using the same code that the site has and I'm getting an error:

`Reverse for 'app_list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'app_label': 'reports'}' not found.`

The `admin/my_view` works fine but if I try to access the other pages in the admin such as the index page I am getting the error

Here's the code:

```
#someapp/admin.py

from django.conf.urls import patterns
from django.contrib import admin
from django.http import HttpResponse

def my_view(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello!")

def get_admin_urls(urls):
    def get_urls():
        my_urls = patterns('',
            (r'^my_view/$', admin.site.admin_view(my_view))
         )
        return my_urls + urls
    return get_urls

admin_urls = get_admin_urls(admin.site.get_urls())
admin.site.get_urls = admin_urls
```

I am using django 1.8.2, python 2.7

also, what is the best way to add some view or context in the admin's index page?

**UPDATE**

I have tried  Antoine Pinsard's answer and tried this:

```
#admin.py
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite
class MyAdminSite(AdminSite):

    def get_urls(self):
        from django.conf.urls import url
        urls = super(MyAdminSite, self).get_urls()
        urls += [
            url(r'^my_view/$', self.admin_view(self.my_view))
        ]
        return urls

    def my_view(self, request):
        return HttpResponse("Hello!")

admin_site = MyAdminSite()
```

And replacing urls.py's `url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),` to `url(r'^admin/', include(admin_site.urls)),`

and getting:

`Reverse for 'app_list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments`

TRACEBACK:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/@dmin/

Django Version: 1.8.2
Python Version: 2.7.10
Installed Applications:
('grappelli',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sessions.models',
 'frontend',
 'file_maintenance',
 'reports',
 'transactions',
 'admin_reorder',
 'admin_notifications',
 'django_twilio',
 'daterange_filter')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.models.User',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'admin_reorder.middleware.ModelAdminReorder')


Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  157.                     response = middleware_method(request, response)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\admin_reorder\middleware.py" in process_template_response
  134.         self.init_config(request, app_list)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\admin_reorder\middleware.py" in init_config
  21.         admin_index = admin.site.index(request)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in index
  438.                                 current_app=self.name,
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  579.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  496.                              (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /@dmin/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'app_list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'app_label': 'django_twilio'}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Comment: Please provide full traceback. Also, note that patterns is deprecated. You should use a list of `url̀`.

Comment: I have updated my post

Comment: If someone still has an issue with that - you can check that post also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877335/how-to-use-custom-adminsite-class . It's a bit tricky but helps to not override AdminSite instance over the project.

Comment: I wrote about how to extend the admin in detail at https://findwork.dev/blog/integrating-chartjs-django-admin/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This guide looks quite old. I would rather advise you to follow [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#customizing-the-adminsite-class).

`someapp/admin.py`

```
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite
from django.http import HttpResponse

class MyAdminSite(AdminSite):

     def get_urls(self):
         from django.urls import path
         urls = super().get_urls()
         urls += [
             path('my_view/', self.admin_view(self.my_view))
         ]
         return urls

     def my_view(self, request):
         return HttpResponse("Hello!")

admin_site = MyAdminSite()
```

Source: https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.2/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L194-L205

You should also update your `project/urls.py` and replace `path('admin/', admin.site.urls)` by `path('admin/', admin_site.urls)`. Don't forget to `from someapp.admin import admin_site` before.

Answer (score 11):

The guide you linked is old and I was surprised to not find anything directly answering your question in the last year or so.

1. Create a new [Admin Site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite) in your app's *admin.py* or in a convenient place.
2. Create a function in the new *AdminSite* that augments the `get_urls()` function with your extra urls.
3. Make sure your project *urls.py* links to the newly created *AdminSite*.

*The below works with Python 3.5.1 and Django 1.9.6.*

---

**my_app/admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite
from django.http import HttpResponse

from my_app.models import SomeModel


class MyAdminSite(AdminSite):

    def custom_view(self, request):
        return HttpResponse("Test")

    def get_urls(self):
        from django.conf.urls import url
        urls = super(MyAdminSite, self).get_urls()
        urls += [
            url(r'^custom_view/$', self.admin_view(self.custom_view))
        ]
        return urls

admin_site = MyAdminSite()


@admin.register(SomeModel, site=admin_site)
class SomeModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

**my_project/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include

from my_app.admin import admin_site

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin_site.urls),
    ...
]
```

Comment: Upvoted for a clear and working example. Any idea how to make this work with _multiple_ projects though, instead of just one?

Comment: @dKen I'm confused. Do you mean multiple Django projects? If so I'm not sure that's possible.

Comment: terribly sorry, I mixed up my nomenclature! I meant to ask how I can get this to work with multiple _apps_. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Well, this *will* work for multiple apps... you'll just have import the instantiated class into all your apps: `from common.admin import admin_site`

Comment: @DanielvanFlymen , will third party apps admin includes works in that way? I meant that some packages have auto rigister themselves to the index page with all functions just after installation and adding to INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: This made the app disappear from the admin "homepage" - is that the expected behavior?

Comment: i'm django 1.11 and the link on admin home page takes me to another page. Any reasons?

Answer (score 1):

For Django 1.4+ here is the solution:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import MyModel


class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (...)

    def custom_admin_view(self, request):
        # your logic here
        if request.method == 'POST':
            ...
        else:
            ...
        return HttpResponse(...)

    def get_urls(self):
        additional_urls = [
            url(r'^custom/$', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.custom_admin_view), name='custom')
        ]
        # append your custom URL BEFORE default ones
        return additional_urls + super().get_urls()


admin.site.register(MyModel, MyAdmin)
```

It's important to append your custom URL **before** all others. Otherwise you might get redirect to admin `change_view` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This code below will [override](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-the-default-admin-site) the default admin site to write your custom view.

Works for Django >= 2.1 :

###myproject/admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.http import HttpResponse

class MyAdminSite(admin.AdminSite):

    def my_view(self, request): # your custom view function
        return HttpResponse("Test")

    def get_urls(self):
        from django.urls import path

        urlpatterns = super().get_urls()
        urlpatterns += [
            path('my_view/', self.admin_view(self.my_view))
        ]
        return urlpatterns
```

###myproject/apps.py

```
from django.contrib.admin.apps import AdminConfig

class MyAdminConfig(AdminConfig):
    default_site = 'myproject.admin.MyAdminSite'
```

###myproject/settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'myproject.apps.MyAdminConfig',  # replaces 'django.contrib.admin'
    ...
]
```

Then go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/my_view/