# Add custom page to django admin without a model

Tags: python, django, admin

I'm trying to add a custom page to the admin without a model association.

This is what I achieved so far.

```
class MyCustomAdmin(AdminSite):

    def get_urls(self):
        from django.conf.urls import url

        urls = super(MyCustomAdmin, self).get_urls()
        urls += [
            url(r'^my_custom_view/$', self.admin_view(MyCustomView.as_view()))
        ]
        return urls

class MyCustomView(View):
    template_name = 'admin/myapp/views/my_custom_template.html'

    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, self.template_name, {})

    def post(self, request):
      # Do something
      pass

admin_site = MyCustomAdmin()

admin_site.register(MyModel1)
admin_site.register(MyModel2)
# etc...
```

This is actually working but the problem is that with this solution I loose some apps from the Django admin interface (account, auth, socialaccounts, sites).

Comment: Instead of replacing the `AdminSite`, try creating a custom `ModelAdmin`, for which you can define custom views: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls

Answer (score 4):

This is because your other admins are using the default `admin.site`. You need to totally replace the default `admin.site` with your own [as explained here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#customizing-the-adminsite-class) (you may also want to [read this too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877335/how-to-use-custom-adminsite-class)).

Or you can just do it piggy-style by monkeypatching the default `admin.site.get_urls()` method:

```
from django.contrib import admin

_admin_site_get_urls = admin.site.get_urls

def get_urls():        
    from django.conf.urls import url
    urls = _admin_site_get_urls()
    urls += [
            url(r'^my_custom_view/$',
                 admin.site.admin_view(MyCustomView.as_view()))
        ]
    return urls

admin.site.get_urls = get_urls
```

Legal disclaimer : I won't be held responsible for any kind of any unwanted side-effect of this "solution", including (but not restricted too) your coworkers defenestrating you on the next code review. It's a dirty solution. It's a mess. It stinks. It's evil. You shouldn't do that, really.

Comment: Where do I put this code?