# How to sumbit form from django admin panel

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I've already made lots of search but couldn't find the appropriate answer to my question.

Is it possible to submit form from template in admin panel? I have a template like this:

```
{% block content %}
{% load static %}

<form action="find_tr" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

    Enter url: <input type="text" name="url"><br><br>
    
    <input type="submit">
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

I can submit it from template itself but , what i want is to make it possible through admin panel.

For now it looks like this:

[image]

The same should be possible from admin panel:
[image]

Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add custom page to django admin without a model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41423711/add-custom-page-to-django-admin-without-a-model)

Comment: it doesn't look like the optimal solution. Is there any other solution for it?

Comment: Can't you just click "Add Tournament" in the top right corner?