# Django run function on logging out of admin page

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm trying to find a way to handle on admin logout (django admin page), files in a certain folder will get deleted. Because i have a function on certain admin interactions, files will get saved to a folder and i would like these files to get deleted when the admin logging out of the admin page.

I only know about Django detect user logout on browser close like so:

```
if settings.SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE:
```

What i would like to do is to override the logout function of admin site to execute a function and delete files in a folder. I can see that the logout function exists in https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L349 but how do i override it and add my delete files function into it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to override the `logout` function itself, you'll have to subclass the `AdminSite` class and create your own class with overriding implementation of logout.

Check this for how to customize AdminSite: [How to use custom AdminSite class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877335/how-to-use-custom-adminsite-class)

You can also use the logout signal to run addition functions after user logout.

Check:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#module-django.contrib.auth.signals